# ERR Failed to serve quic connection; Cloudflare Quick Tunnels

Tags: cloudflare, self-hosting, cloudflare-argo

I am attempting to host a local webpage for my friends to see and interact with over Cloudflare quick tunnels and attempted to start it following the guide [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps/do-more-with-tunnels/trycloudflare/) but when I do, it repeats this set of messages and repeats 4 or 5 times, and gives a 1033 error when I attempt to view the generated URL.

> 2022-08-12T20:37:27Z ERR Failed to serve quic connection error="Unauthorized: Failed to get tunnel" connIndex=0 ip=[removed]
> 2022-08-12T20:37:27Z ERR Register tunnel error from server side
> error="Unauthorized: Failed to get tunnel" connIndex=0 ip=[removed]
> 2022-08-12T20:37:27Z INF Retrying connection in up to 2s seconds
> connIndex=0 ip=[removed]

I have tried many times and am confident I am using the correct local URL, running

```
cloudflared tunnel --url http://localhost:60662
```

and the result is always the same.

Comment: Is it actually a secure connection with an SSL layer and encryption?
 If so its not http 
but https instead

Comment: @easleyfixed could you clarify where that would make a difference? Or do you just mean the URL I'm referencing, because I'm copying that out of a browser where the page is loaded, so it should be consistent with whatever is actually running!

Comment: Hmm okay, just sometimes unexpected Unauthorized can happen when you put http instead of https, but if you copied and pasted it,  then its Unauthorized for a different reason it seems.

Comment: I'm facing the same! Did you fix this?

Comment: @XowmikXoss unfortunately no, i gave up eventually